# How to statistically analyse gene-environment interactions pairs?

Tags: p-value, multiple-comparisons, biostatistics, permutation-test

I am new here so sorry I hope I am using the forum correctly. Also, my knowledge on statistics is very basic and is something I am working towards learning more.

I am studying gene-environment interactions and how they are relevant for a given phenotype. I have two sets: 1) one set of around 1000 candidate genes, 2) one set of 60 relevant xenobiotics. I could just look at these twos sets and see how many interactions pairs I have and with how many relevant xenobiotics each gene interacts with (and vice-versa). However, I thought it would be nice to give the analysis, if possible, a statistical meaning.

My null hypothesis would be: the proportion of xenobiotics relevant for the phenotype that gene A interacts with is equal to the proportion of xenobiotics non-relevant for the pehnotype that same gene interacts with.

The alternative hypothesis: the proportion of xenobiotics relevant for the phenotype that gene A interacts with is higher than the proportion of xenobiotics non-relevant for the pehnotype that same gene interacts with.

This would indicate me if gene A interacts "preferentially" with xenobiotics relevant for the phenotype.
(I have all of the data. I know exactly with how many relevant and non-relevant xenobiotics each gene interacts with).

The biggest issue here is that while I have 60 relevant xenobiotics, I have around 7000 non-relevant xenobiotics, meaning that the two groups I am comparing have really different population sizes. I am just really looking to inputs of how should I analyse this.

There have been some ideas:

- Just apply a regular Fisher or Chi-square test for each gene and correct for multiple testing (but I don't think this is enough)
- It has been proposed that I compare the group of 60 relevant xenobiotics with ~1000 groups of random 60 non-relevant xenobiotics. But I am confused of what test would I use here (just perform ~1000 of Fisher tests for each gene?
- Perform a Permutation test, which is something I am learning more about.

I am thankful for any inputs you might have

Thank you and sorry for the long post